# Difficulties with scope in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scope

I'm trying to build an application where there's a device with an expire date:
the expire date must be created with values from 2 other tables: history (last date) & model (interval)

I've create following scope in my **Device** model:

```
public function scopeExpiryDate($query, $operator) {
    if ($this->histories->last() != null) {
        $cal_date = $this->histories->sortBy('date')->last()->date;
        $interval = $this->product->interval;
        return $query->where($cal_date->addDays($interval), $operator, Carbon::now());
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Then I could use the next line:

```
$devices->ExpiryDate('<=')->get();
```

## Update

like @ceejayoz told in the comments I checked the scopes section on the Laravel-site.
I edited this question.

*So how do I get this scope working?*

Comment: You should look at the documentation on Laravel scopes. This would be a perfect situation for that.

Comment: Ok scopes could help me further, but it seems I can't create the right query for this one, I tried this but it doens't work:

    public function scopeExpiryDate($query, $operator) {
        if ($this->histories->last() != null) {
            $cal_date = $this->histories->sortBy('date')->last()->date;
            $interval = $this->product->interval;
            return $query->where($cal_date->addDays($interval), $operator, Carbon::now());
        }
        return $query;
    }
 
How do I get this working?

Comment: What is the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've found the solution. It was not found in the scopes, but in adding a attribute.
I did the following in my Device model:

```
public function getExpirydateAttribute() {
    if ($this->histories->last() != null) {
        $cal_date = $this->histories->sortBy('date')->last()->date;
        $interval = $this->product->interval;
        return $cal_date->addDays($interval);
    }
    return Carbon::now();
}
```

and in my view I can call something like this:

```
$devices->filter(function($item){ return $item->Expirydate > now()->modify('last day of this month'); })->count()
```

Thanks to the people who answered to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$cal_date` is a `Carbon\Carbon` instance, you can use this query:

`$query->whereDate($cal_date->addDays($interval), $operator, Carbon::now());`

For more information, there's a great tutorial on date filtering [here](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/)

Comment: Not entirely what I was looking for, but i've found the solution. I added an extra attribute to my model. I'll make an answer for this.